# Update packages Texlive 2022

Tags: texlive

I'm in the process of switching to Debian, and I'm interested in updating packages since I'm coming from Windows 10 MikTex. I read this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/230596 and I understood that for updating packages I have to issue `tlmgr update --all`.
My question is that issuing that command, I will have all the time updates as I had when using Miktex. If so, why should I install another Texlive in 2023?

Comment: texlive only updates packages not binaries.

Comment: TeXLive only (for various reasons) provides updates to a given version for a little less than a year. As these (at least when it is Upstream TeXLive and not Debian/TeXLive) can live side by side, these year releases can be useful as you can go back in time. Say I have a manuscript that compiled with TL16 but not does not with TL22, then I can just use TL16-frozen as I have it on disk.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer @daleif maybe I'm not used with a specialized language, that's why I did not understand `binaries` frozen Texlive etc. I installed Texlive over the internet and for example I see here https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.4074.1654525684.3195.ctan-ann@ctan.org that `latexindent` received an update yesterday. Is it possible to have this update in Texlive?

Comment: Of course. Just have your TeX Live's Package Manager update the files.

Comment: The important thing for you is to understand that there is “TeX Live provided by Debian” and “upstream TeX Live”. The former is the easiest to install for a Debian user, since it's installed exactly like other packages. Upstream TeX Live can live side by side with the TL from Debian, is not difficult to install either (read the instructions), but much easier to keep very up-to-date: you can update it every day if you want, instead of depending on Debian release cycles (or on Debian package updates in the case of Debian `unstable`).

Comment: Upstream TeX Live can be installed & updated under a specific user account (e.g., `texlive`), and then used by any user account. This way, the installation/update procedure can't write anywhere (in my example, it is limited to where user `texlive` has permission to write).

Comment: @frougon I know about TeX Live provided by Debian, but I preferred to install it via `https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html`. So far, so good for me. Just issued `sudo ./install-tl -gui`, chose default full scheme, also mark `create simlink directories` or smth and everything is good. I didn't even need to export `$PATH` in my `profile`. Now, issuing `sudo tlmgr update --all` is updating my TexLive. I read the part with user `texlive` here on tex.stackexchange.com, I tried, but it was way too complicated for me. After everything written here, you have any further advice, pls share.

Comment: Installing with root priviledges was totally unnecessary... The only thing you gained is not to have to change the PATH setting. Hmm.

Comment: Issuing `./install-tl -gui` didn't work for me cause it asked for permission

Comment: Personally, I do `ssh -X texlive@localhost` after temporarily uncommenting `X11Forwarding yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then doing `systemctl restart ssh.service` (as root). An alternative is to perform a graphical login as user `texlive` (or install/update in text mode).