# tlmgr tells me my Local TeXLive (2019) is older than remote repository (2022) despite running TeXLive version 2022

Tags: installing, ubuntu, linux

Hellou I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64.

I previously had a TeXLive 2019 install on my machine via `apt`. But because of a problem with `tlmgr` (the Native TeXLive manager) concerning incompatible repository "versions", I wanted to perform a proper TeXLive install via the provided guide on https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html.

So I `sudo apt purge texlive-full` in order to remove my TeXLive install and then proceeded with the quick-install from tug.org.

As it is now the install was successful (added everything into my `PATH`,`MANPATH` and `INFOPATH`). **BUT** the problem was still there.

Searching for a fix I ran the `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` script provided by my mirror https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/ which is up to date (Last modified on 17-Apr-2022 02:43). But I still get

```
wenigwil@kubuntboo:Downloads$ sudo tlmgr --verify-repo=none update --all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2022).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details
```

with the emphasis on `tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2022).`

, despite of

```
wenigwil@kubuntboo:Downloads$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 63033 (2022-04-15 07:19:42 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2022
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2022
```

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Root has a different path to a normal user ...

Comment: @JosephWright thank you for pointing that out. But if I run `tlmgr update --self --all` the manager tells me that "You don't have permission to change the installation in any way, [...] Please run this programm as administrator.".

Comment: You need to add your TeX live install directory also to the sudo path. See https://superuser.com/q/927512 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191.

Comment: Try `sudo <full-path-to>/tlmgr ...`

Comment: In any case it seems that the `apt purge` did not succeed in uninstalling the complete apt-TeX live. If all paths are set up correctly that does not matter a great deal, but you may want to look into uninstalling all bits of the repository TeX Live.

Comment: @JosephWright that did work!

Comment: Issuing `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self --all` resulted in no error messages. It also stated that my package repository is verified which sounds great.

Comment: You could easily have installed TeX Live as a non-root user. Then you don't have to worry *at all* about the possibility of messing up your installation. See my tips [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/646962/73317).

Comment: @frougon There's more information in my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187379/ if somebody wants a step-by-step. There's a lot of other more general information about installing vanilla TL on that page, too. (My two pennyworth on non-root installation is just a detail.)

Comment: You may want to look into convincing your package manager to let you get rid of whatever package provides `tlmgr`. You also need to prevent it pulling TL packages back in if you install or update something like an editor. The best way is through the use of dummy packages, which depend on your distro.

Answer (score -1):

personal experience:

1] delete tlmgr
==> which tlmgr ; and delete it, including its link if any

2] reinstall TexLive2022 (select scheme at least i: infrastructure-only scheme)

Comment: This is really not good advice. Deleting things your package manager installed is *not* a good idea. Take the time to manage the packages properly so this isn't necessary or, failing that, please don't recommend this to others. Aside from anything else, this will leave a bunch of other stuff in place and be undone whenever the package providing `tlmgr` gets updated.